# In-App purchase with Android Application

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play-services, in-app-billing

I have developed an `Android` application which run three platforms, Initially for 15 days I am giving my application for trail period and after 15 days the user have to subscribe the application (They can purchase) to use it uninterruptedly rest of the time , I was planning to use third party payment gateways like (Stripe,Paypal) but I think the Platform like Android only allowing third party payment gateways for selling physical goods like (Books , Electronics items etc. ) But in our case we just going to sell an upgraded App which is a digital content.My Question is can we sell the App Upgrade features through Stripe payment gateway or any third party payment gateway???
IF not I found the platform `Android` providing Service API's for `In-App Purchase` inside the App.
So My Question is, Do i need only `In-App purchase` service for selling App in `Playstore`???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, yes - the Android [In-App Billing](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html) can help you with selling digital content inside your application. Though Stripe has an [Android Integration](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android), I believe it's indicated there that you can only use Stripe for physical goods or services.

In your use-case, I'd suggest you use the native In-App Billing.